# How to trim commit comments in "git branch -avv"

Tags: git

I wrote a bash function which do some handy tasks on entering a git repository on console. It also gives me an overview of all branches using `git branch -avv`

For my inconvenience, git is "flooding" me when writing the full changelog comments which often doesn't fit the console line width

Trimming these with pipes like `cut -c-$(tput cols);` will remove coloring if enabled in git config ;(

**The Answer**: is there a way to configure git in a *native* way, to just output the first XX chars of the commit message? My goal is to archive this without need of further command line tools I don't know collogues have had installed them.

---

**edit**:
Thanks to answer #2 (Max Nanasy): use of `--color` option will force coloring

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
 git log --oneline | cut -b 1-20
```

May be better (without the SHA):

```
git log --pretty=format:'%s' | cut -b 1-20
```

Comment: it's not a full LOG what I'm looking for, but just a list of branches, with coloring ('cause better readable / gives me a peak overview)

Answer (score 1):

`git branch --color -avv | cut -c-$(tput cols)`

Comment: thanks for pointing out `--color` option. I precised your answer why this helped out. Nevertheless: it solves the coloring cut problem but will not answer the question: How to trim / cut in git native without other shell tools